# Gnuradio number of output items

Tags: gnuradio

I'm trying to display "number of items on the output stream" in the flowgraph.

Is there a way to access the function: `block__nitems_written(unsigned int which_output)` from the flowgraph?

So far I have tried "from gnuradio import gr" and then use `gr.block__nitems_written(0)` as a value in a variable. The error I get is:

> module object has no attribute `block__nitems_written`.

I think I am not calling the function properly. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing things! That's not a property of a flow graph.

Each block has its own number of items that it's written to its output ports.

Hence, it's a method of `gr.block`, which you can only call with a block instance, i.e. typically as `self.nitems_written(0)` **within** a block's `work` method.

Comment: Full question: Thanks that clarifies things. I have one follow up question on the point                                                                                   Each block has its own number of items:                                                                                                                     Let's say I have Block A -----> Block B ------> Block C and all of them are sync blocks, will each of them write different number of items on the output port or the scheduler decides how many items to be written for all the blocks at the beginning? Thanks

Comment: the question is *when*? These blocks don't run synchronously, nor are they forced to consume all the input they get at once; so your question has no clear answer. When the flowgraph is done running because Block A decided it has no more items to produce, and then Block B consumed the last item and produced its last output item, and C then consumed all these, they'll have all the same numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your help

Comment: might clarify things: [https://www.gnuradio.org/blog/buffers](https://web.archive.org/web/20170118181415/http://gnuradio.org:80/blog/buffers/)

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this is very good explanation of the way buffers work